# Gradle failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:10.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a problem with my gradle :

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:10.0.1
```

This is my gradle module app file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.the.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 44
        versionName "2.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.2@aar'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my project gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I really don't understand why it's not working. I try to change the         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0' to the version 3 but I need a key, and I don't want to use Firebase.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 6):

Change the classpath in your build.gradle (project level)

from:

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'

to:

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: Should have beed accepted, this answers the problem of Jewom (and mine). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem. I solved it by accident. I was making sure all my libraries were up to date in the SDK Manager when I commented out

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in my gradle module app file. After removing this line everything compiled normally. I hope this helps.